# CMake to Qt Creator .pro file; Build specific CMake project from Qt Creator

Tags: visual-studio, qt, cmake, qt-creator, qmake

`Qt Creator` does an excellent job with with parsing and building a `CMake` project. The problem is that when the CMake is too big and has sub-projects, it takes a long time to build.

`CMake` does have the ability to convert a `CMake` project to a `Visual Studio` solution. But since I am using `Qt Creator,` I'd also like to be able to convert a `CMake` project to a `Qt Creator` project.

Is there a straightforward way of accomplishing this task? I have googled, but haven't found anything.

P.S. Or, alternatively, I want the ability to just a build a specific `CMake` project from `Qt Creator,` and not the whole "solution". `Visual Studio` allows you to do it, `Qt Creator` does not. Unless it does and I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some digging in `Qt Creator` and it turns out that it is indeed possible to set which particular `CMake` sub-project to build.

On the right hand-side where you see the column `Welcome/Edit/Design/Projects/Help,` go to `Projects` and select `Build` on the configuration that you're building:

[image]

Then on the right hand-side you'll see on the top a `CMake` dialog and right below it `Build Steps` dialog with all the `CMake` sub-projects loaded. By default `all` is checked. You can change that selection to whatever sub-project you want to. Obviously if you have a number of sub-projects that are libraries and you're modifying most of the time your executable project and running, then the choice would be the very first one, titled `Current Executable:`

[image]

Comment: Another thing you may want to try is to use `Ninja` generator in `CMake`, which is faster than `make` used bu default.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak, how easy/hard it is to do it? Where can I find documentation on enabling `Ninja` in `CMake?` I already have a huge `CMake` project with sub-projects.

Comment: When you use `cmake`, it actually generates files for another tool which will build your project. By example `cmake` can generate `Makefiles` to build under `Linux` with `make` (or under `Windows` with `mingw` (which is used by `QtCreator`). It can also generate `vcproj` files for `Visual Studio`. It is up to you. You can use `Ninja` (which should work with `QtCreator`) just google for `ninja build` and for `cmake generators`. You don't need to change anything in your `CMake` project.